# Multiple types in a single c++ vector

Tags: c++, vector

I wonder if i could store different types of non-native data into a single vector?
it goes like this:

```
class foo
{
    private:
        int x;
    public:
        foo(int a=0):x(a){}
        int getx() { return x; }
        void setx(int a=0) { x=a; }
};
class var:public foo
{
    private:
        int y;
    public:
        var(int a=0, int b=0):foo(a), y(b){}
        int gety() { return y; }
        void sety(int a=0) { y=a; }
};
class var1:public foo
{
    private:
        int z;
    public:
        var(int a=0, int b=0):foo(a), z(b){}
        int getz() { return z; }
        void setz(int a=0) { z=a; }
};
```

How to declare a vector to hold data of both `var` and `var1` types?
I could store them in a `std::vector<foo>`, but then they'd be treated as if they are of `foo` types

Comment: We seem to be getting this question a lot these days. Is someone telling beginners that storing different types in one container is a good idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vectors and polymorphism in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126578/vectors-and-polymorphism-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a sub-type of `foo` to a `std::vector<foo>`, you will lose the sub-type information. See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) for more info.

A `std::vector<foo>` container can only hold objects of type `foo`. To be able store objects that are derived from `foo`, you'll have to allocate objects on the heap and store the pointers in a `vector` of pointers, preferably a `vector` of smart pointers - `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<foo>>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<foo>>`.

Comment: Ah, apparently that means i made a big mistake, or rather, the lecturers in my campus did. Either they overlooked this bit or maybe they plainly have no idea about this. This was supposed to be an exercise for class relationships. Man, i'm starting to worry about my future in programming.

Comment: As long as you learn from those mistakes, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use polymorphism. So instead of declaring as `std::vector<foo>`, you declare as pointer of the base class: `std::vector<foo*>`.

Then in your function you can declare as

```
vector<foo*> bar;

bar.push_back( new var1() );
```