# Adding instances of a template class to a vector (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, generics, polymorphism

In the code below, I get a compiler error when trying to push `fooBaz` onto `v`. This surpises me since `Baz` is a derived class of `Bar`.

Why is this not allowed, and what can I do if want to put several `Foo` instances, templated on classes derived from the same base class, into a vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Foo {};

struct Bar {};
struct Baz : public Bar {};

int main() {
  
  Foo<Bar> fooBar;
  Foo<Baz> fooBaz;
  
  std::vector<Foo<Bar>> v;
  v.push_back(fooBar);
  v.push_back(fooBaz);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "This surpises me since Baz is a derived class of Bar" - But `Foo<Baz>` isn't a derived class of `Foo<Bar>`.

Comment: `Foo<Bar>` and `Foo<Baz>` are completely unrelated classes, why would you expect that `std::vector<T>` can contain mixed types, unless these are pointers or references to `virtual`ly inherited classes

Comment: To make a cooling analogy: a class template is a recipe, where the template parameters are the ingredients.  If you change the ingredients, you change the dish, and you don't want to store different dishes in the same bowl.

Comment: Haha, good analogy Nathan. Thank you all for answers, v helpful.

Comment: Java programmer?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont yes haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, templates are like recipes. You need to instantiate a class template to get a class, before it is just a template. There is no implicit relation between different instantiations (other than being instantiations of the same template). Maybe this gets more clear when you consider following example:

```
template<typename T> struct Foo {};

template <> struct Foo<int> { void bar(){} };
template <> struct Foo<double> { void moo(){} };

int main() {
    Foo<int> x;
    x.bar();
    Foo<double> y;
    y.moo();
}
```

`Foo<int>` and `Foo<double>` are two unrelated types with completely different methods. If they were not instantiations of a template, but "ordinary" types with different members you would not be surprised that you cannot push a `FooA` into a `std::vector<FooB>`.

A `std::vector<Foo<Bar>>` can only hold elements of type `Foo<Bar>`. The vector is not aware that this type is the result of instantiating the template `Foo`. And even if it was, you cannot assign a `Foo<Bar>` to a `Foo<Baz>` unless you provide a conversion.

---

Actually there is more to your misunderstanding that needs to be debunked. Suppose you have a `std::vector<Bar>` then you also **cannot** push a `Baz` to that vector. See here for why not: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). And here for what to do instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126649/4117728.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Java Generics are not the same kind of thing as C++ templates.

C++ values of class type are not the same thing as Java reference variables of class type.

You are running into both problems here.

C++ templates generate a new, unrelated type for each set of template arguments.  You can create a common base, but you have to do it yourself.

Java Generics, under the hood, actually create a single class.  It then writes casting operations at inputs and outputs.

So a Java Generic, `Foo<Base>` and `Foo<Derived>` are related, because the the Java Generic actually creates a `Foo<Object>` then wraps it up in casts, and those casts in `Foo<Base>` and `Foo<Derived>` are compatible. (well, not always `Object`, you mark up the generic arguments with information that Java uses to determine what the actual type it writes its Generic for, but that gives you the idea).

In C++, there is no relation.  (well, template pattern matching gives you a compile-time relation, but no runtime relation at all)

The second problem is that you are treating values of class type like references.  In C++, a `Foo` is an actual foo.  It represents a block of memory that is an instance of that class.  In Java, a `Foo` is a smart pointer to an object on the heap somewhere that obeys the `Foo` protocol (is a derived class).

You cannot easily make a value of type `Foo` in Java, and you cannot easily make a mark and sweep smart pointer to a `Foo` in C++.

```
Foo<Bar> fooBar;
Foo<Baz> fooBaz;
```

these are two unrelated types.  They are stored on the stack (automatic storage).

```
std::vector<Foo<Bar>> v;
```

This stores a buffer of memory containing `Foo<Bar>` objects packed together.

```
v.push_back(fooBar);
```

This copies a `fooBar` instance from automatic storage into the `vector`.

```
v.push_back(fooBaz);
```

This doesn't work, because `fooBar` and `fooBaz` are unrelated types.

Now, prior to [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) reflection, mimicing what Java does is difficult in C++.  You have to do some steps manually.

First, instruct `Foo` to understand inheritance **when told so manually**:

```
struct empty_t {};
template<class T, class Base=empty_t>
class Foo:Foo<Base> {};
template<>
class Foo<empty_t, empty_t> {
  virtual ~Foo() {}
};

struct Bar {};
struct Baz : public Bar {};


auto fooBar = std::make_unique<Foo<Bar>>();
auto fooBaz = std::make_unique<Foo<Baz, Bar>>();

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo<Bar>>> v;
v.push_back(std::move(fooBar));
v.push_back(std::move(fooBaz));
```

this compiles.

In [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) compile time reflection should let you auto-detect the base classes of `Baz` and have `Foo<Baz>` automatically inherit from `Foo<Bases>...` if you want.

Now, inheritance is only one kind of way to handle polymorphism in C++, but I think is enough for today.