# List or Array of Elements of different datatypes

Tags: c++

I want to store 6 pointers to objects. But the Pointers can be in any order and point to different instances of (12) subclasses  of one superclass, so they are possibly all of different types.
Arrays and such don't work, because the superclass is virtual.
Vectors and Tuples don't work, because the datatypes are of no specific order and are not known at compile time.
Im fairly new to C++ and I'm running out of Ideas.
Here some code to elaborate the problem:

```
baseclass{
 getfoobar()=0;
}

subclass1{
getfoobar(){...}
}

subclass2{
getfoobar(){...}
}
---
#include <otherclasses.h>
memoryclass{
baseclass mem[6];
}
```

is basically what im trying.

Comment: pointers to subclasses that share a common base are 
homogeneous. And its not clear why "no specific order" or "not known at compile time" excludes vectors

Comment: If the objects all belong to the same inheritance hierarchy, and are properly polymorphic, then why can't you use a pointer to the common base-class?

Comment: I suggest you to write soem code and include it in the question instead of pondering too much about what isnt possible

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, that the base class is virtual and the Compiler is complaining, that virtual classes cant have instances.

Comment: Nevertheless, you can store a pointer to a class. To store a pointer, it's regardless whether it's instanceable or not. (You can even store a `void*` regardless that `void` represents nothing.)

Comment: I guess you made the mistake of trying to declare a `std::vector<SuperClass>` when you wanted a `std::vector<SuperClass*>`. This is easier when you include a [mcve] of your code in the question.

Comment: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0861f086bbc46dc)

Comment: details do matter, and some are rather pedantic when it is about code. The code you posted has more syntax errors than anything else. Why don't you include an actual example of subclasses and your attempt to create the vector? Anyhow I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126578/vectors-and-polymorphism-in-c (or any other q&a with same keywords)

Comment: You have to dynamically allocate the subclasses and use pointers to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You CAN create a vector of superclass pointers. It will achieve what you want, as it will call the overwritten function. This is of course assuming you are talking about inheritance, like:

```cpp
#include <vector>

using type = ????;

class A {
    virtual type foo() = 0;
}
class B : A {
    type foo() override { ... }
}
class C : A {
    type foo() override { ... }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<A*> arr;
    arr.push_back(new B);
    arr.push_back(new C);
}
```

Now if I misunderstood and this doesn't work for some reason (i.e. they just share the function and are not actually related classes), you can do something like this, but it is not very nice:

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using type = ?????;

template <class T> requires requires(T t){
    { t.foo() } -> std::same_as<type>;
}
std::function<type()> getFunction(T* t){
    return [t](){ return t->foo(); };
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::function<type()>> arr;
    arr.push_back(getFunction(new B));
    arr.push_back(getFunction(new C));
}
```

I don't recommend this over the first option unless you have very good reason to do this.

Note: Since you didn't specify return type I winged it with `?????`

Also: In the second you can replace `template<class T> requires ... std::function<type()>`, with just `template<class T> std::function<type()>`, if the compiler doesn't like `#include <concepts>`

Comment: Thank you for the great answer despite my subpar Question. The first example is exactly what I ment. But because my Subclasses have functions of their own, my Compiler complains, that the baseclass has no such function.

Comment: @PeterBrand Yeah you have to declare any function that you might want to use as virtual so that you can access it from the pointer of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try std::set<Superclass*>. Use pointers to your base superclass instead pointers to particular subclasses.
Actually I used std::shared_ptr<> smart pointer template to avoid raw memory management.
Example code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class baseclass {
public:
    virtual std::string getfoobar() = 0;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<baseclass> baseclass_ptr;

class subclass1 : public baseclass{
public:
    std::string getfoobar() override {
        return "from subclass1";
    }
};

class subclass2 : public baseclass{
public:
    std::string getfoobar() override {
        return "from subclass2";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Use current time as seed for random generator
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(nullptr)));

    std::set<baseclass_ptr> container;
    // Randomly generate number of elements
    const int random_count = std::rand() % 10 + 1; 
    for (int i = 0; i < random_count; ++i) {
        // Randomly create subclass1 or subclass2
        if (std::rand() % 2) {
            container.insert(std::make_shared<subclass1>());
        }
        else {
            container.insert(std::make_shared<subclass2>());
        }
    }
    
    // Iterate resulting container
    std::cout << "size = " << container.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto iterator : container) {
        std::cout << "getfoobar(): " << iterator->getfoobar() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```